Optimal compensation/teaching load policies?
I am a faculty member at a primarily undergraduate institution (PUI). This past academic year, the administration decided to make some changes to the way that teaching load is calculated resulting in many faculty members being unsatisfied.
According to our faculty handbook, we are expected teach 21-24 load credits per year. Typically, a single load credits correspond exactly to the number of credits a student earns for a class. However, the handbook makes it clear that for classes of larger than 50, an extra load credit may be assessed and for classes of 6-10 students, there may be a reduction in teaching load assessed by one credit. However, there are extra caveats for certain types of courses. For example, If you run an independent studies course, you get one load credit for three students; one can surmise that if you do not have three students, then you may get less than one load credit to run the independent studies course.
This system obviously has some unfortunate consequences. As an example, some of our upper division, major only classes will regularly fall into the 6-10 student cut-off resulting in a reduction of load by one credit. Of course, just because a class has 10 students instead of 11 does not mean that you are doing one load credit less worth of work.
So my question is this: what would be an optimal way to assign load credit for faculty that doesn't penalize the faculty unnecessarily and does take into account the variety of classes that are taught (including the variety of content, class sizes, time required by the faculty, etc.)? Ideally the optimal method would also make administrators happy.

Did the faculty have any say in this scheme? If not, why not?

Note the inherent conflict of interest between faculty and administration in such things. So, "optimal" from whose standpoint?

"Optimal" seems entirely subjective, and opinion based questions are discouraged on this site. Better might be to ask about different kinds of policies that are common, and their pros and cons.

Actually, the question is improperly posed. Optimal for the faculty is one course per term with about 20 students, the course chosen by the faculty member. But that is impossible financially and doesn't guarantee that the curriculum is covered. Optimal from the administration is, perhaps, to pack students into as few courses as possible given the seating room of their campus, requiring the smallest possible faculty. But that is educationally counterproductive.
What I find optimal is a system negotiated honestly and fairly with the faculty for the overall structure, with plenty of room for exceptions and faculty choice when it is time to schedule.
Two institutions with which I've been associated had a two course rule. Everyone taught two courses per term (actually stated as four per year at one of them). There was some choice of courses but one of those courses might be huge by their standards and one might be a small seminar. Everyone knew that occasionally they would have a large class and need to manage TAs. But the department head could then promise a better situation for the coming term, or even time off, or whatever. People could ask for specific courses, but conflicts needed to be worked out. If people trust the system and the administration it can work.
So, the system was flexible and had room to negotiate.
If you want to get a sense of what a system like yours will entail, you can take enrollment data from previous years and figure the actual loads of each faculty member with the new system. Does it balance? Or does it have winners and losers?

Teaching load policy is typically not a universal policy that holds across the entire institution, but is set at an intermediate level such as a college or a division. This is because there are indeed large differences between how different departments approach fulfilling their teaching mission and satisfying the particular needs of their students.
Within a relatively focused administrative division such as “engineering” or “mathematical and physical sciences”, the similarities are much greater, so there is a much better chance for a dean or other administrator, working with the departments under them, to formulate a coherent and fair policy.
The general idea that teaching credits should depend in some way on class size is reasonable and common. All other things being equal, the labor of an instructor who teaches a class with 200 students has greater economic value than the labor of an instructor teaching a very specialized class with only 5 students. And while all other things are never truly equal, they are often approximately so. Teaching load policies are not an exact science but try to roughly capture a general sort of truth. As such, the policy you describe in the question does not sound to me as one that necessarily does a terrible job of aligning the institution’s economic resources with the combined needs of the faculty and the students. Is it “optimal”? Probably not. But is it reasonable? It very well may be.
So what does an “optimal” policy look like? I don’t think anyone can say in general. The details of the precise formula that is seen as optimal in any given situation, if it is even meaningful to ask for such a thing, would depend too strongly on specific details of the institution, its needs, character, and financial situation. All that one can hope for at that level of generality, as Buffy’s answer says, is that the process for arriving at the detailed formula should be fair, and should involve a good faith negotiation between the administration and the faculty, taking into account the needs and resources available to both.
That being said, one feature of an optimal policy (or any policy) that is indeed completely general is that some people will always find some aspects of it to complain about.

Another point is that the 200 student class will typically involve the labor of several TAs as well as the instructor.
